# How to show that voltages on diagram are 120° apart?

Tags: transformer, ac, voltage-measurement, three-phase, graph

So i'm doing a matlab simulation of delta wye transformer and would need to show the phase shift between voltages. Here is a picture[image: Three phase voltages] of input voltages so how would I show on this graph mathematically or graphically that these voltages are 120 degrees apart?

I tought of doing it like on this picture,[image: picture] to find degrees or radians and compare them, but on the graph from simulink above numbers are small so I don't know how.

Comment: Compute the phase angle when blue equals yellow.

Comment: You could do a simple fundamental frequency DFT to calculate the voltage phasors. Then plot all of them on a phasor diagram.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly off-beat approach:

[image]

*Figure 1. Intersection of the curves.*

Because they're sinewaves we can use some trig functions.

- At (1) the blue phase is at 0. Let's call this 0°.
- At (2) the blue phase is at 2400. That will be 90°.
- At (3) and (4), the intersection point with the other phases, the voltage is 1200 which is half the peak. We know that \$ sin\ a = 0.5 \$ has two solutions: 30° and 150° and that these are 120° apart.

Comment: And how would it be then for this one https://imgur.com/a/Cckv1p9 ?

Comment: That's a different question.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way would be to put your vertical grid lines at 60 or 120 degree spacing. Then you'll see that the rising-edge zero-crossings of phase 2 are 120 degrees after phase 1, and the zero-crossing of phase 3 is 120 degrees after that.